# How would I delete the first 27 characters from every line Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a log file and I need to remove the first 27 characters off every line. You would have a line like this:

```
2011-09-25 01:25:29 [INFO] <Exazoro> wazup
```

But it needs to be like this:

```
<Exazoro> wazup
```

Comment: you could use some varient of the unix cut command from unxutils or busybox to do that much more easily - does it have to be notepad++?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it dosn't have to be notepad++ its just waht i mainly use and it has macro and plugin support so i guessed there might be something to do that.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use regular expression search, search for `^...........................` and replace with *(empty string)*.

[image]

<sup>Unfortunately, Notepad++ does not support repetition counts like `^.{27}` — the [SciTE regexp documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html) applies here as well.</sup>

---

Alternatively, use rectangular multi-line selection (press `Alt` while selecting) to select these first 27 characters in every line, then press `Delete` or `Backspace`.

[image]

---

Using Unix tools (e.g. Cygwin, UnxUtils) you can use `cut -c28-` or `sed -E "s|^.{27}||"` instead. At least, these are the Linux command line calls you'd use...

Comment: Alt + Shift + right to select the 27 characters in the first row, then Pg Dn whilst still holding Alt + Shift should do it

Comment: For the regex, Notepad++ doesn't follow all the standard regex rules, so I'm not surprised that you couldn't get it to work.  And since it looks like the first 27 characters are a date, time, and error level, a more informative regex might be possible, like `^[0-9\-]+ [0-9:]+ \[[A-Z]+\] `

Comment: Loving the `Alt` for rectangular selection!!

Comment: Alt selection simple and easy. Thanks Daniel Beck.

Comment: wow! thanks for that rectangular selection tip... I wasn't even aware that something like that exists...

Comment: Alt + Shift + PgDwn first, and then Alt + Shift + Right 27 characters worked for me. The regex answers won't work correctly if the strings are longer than 54 characters.

Comment: +1, you just saved my 2 hours. The rectangular selection was a great idea too

Comment: +1 for the Cygwin option, the NPP stucked since im working on huge files and the Cygwin won here

Comment: !!! rectangular multi-line selection !!!  easyyyyyyy.. Great

Answer (score 15):

Since Daniel Beck's answer was originally posted, updates to Notepad++ now support the following regular expression repetition: `^.{27}`
But note with just that expression, Notepad++ will repeatedly remove all characters  from the document until no more than 27 remain.  To avoid this you can use the following Find/Replace:

- Find what: `^.{27}(.*)$`
- Replace with: `$1`

Comment: this works perfectly!

Comment: This solution works in sublime as well!

Comment: This one actually worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Below is the macro way. This is more intuitive for non-technical people:

1) Place cursor on the first line (any cursor position)

2) Click : Macro -> Start Recording

3) Do the following key press activities:

```
* Press the Home key  
* Press Delete key 27 times (till you reach the intended character)
* Press down arrow button.
```

4) Click : Macro -> Stop Recording

5) Click : Run Macro Multiple times -> select Run until
   the end of file -> click Run.

Answer (score 2):

a small improvement to Daniel Beck answer:
Use regular expression search, search for:

```
^...........................(.*.\r\n)
```

and replace with:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 2):

ALT + SHIFT + Mouse selection
(only ALT is not working)

Point at the beginning of the file, go to the end hold ALT+SHIFT and point on the position u want to...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its removing the pattern after starting character as well, & when macro isn't a solution, alt+shift+right drag drop is also not possible because of large data for which someone need to work then below might work.

I have the error file in format of

> [19 Aug 2022 00:00:00:021] ERROR TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler::handleError:95 - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

For which need to remove [19 Aug 2022 00:00:00:021] for which simple but effective solution I used,

1. Copy the data CSV format
2. open in excel
3. Data--> text to columns
4. delimiter used "]" as in this case I do want separation from here
5. Excel done separated out [19 Aug 2022 00:00:00:021] and those error text in just a minute.

Hope some one get this useful.
By this I was able to remove all leading unwanted logging character for large file.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.