# How to remove the first character of every line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete first 27 characters from every line notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/339601/delete-first-27-characters-from-every-line-notepad)

I managed to find an answer to remove the last character from every line in Notepad++, but now I need the same solution for the first character on every line.

This is the solution to the last character:
[image: remove last character]

If someone could let me know how to remove the first, using this method, I would appreciate it please.

Comment: Why not make a new screenshot without the highlight? :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

**Find What:** `^.?(.*)`

**Replace with:** `\1`

**Search Mode** `Regular expression`

[image: the answer]

Answer (score 6):

I realize this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but one way to remove the first character from every line is to use the ALT-mouse drag to select the first column of text.

In case you haven't discovered this feature yet, here's how:

- Move to the top of the text, in front of the first character.
- Press and hold down ALT
- Click and hold down mouse button and select the first character of every line, and release.
- Press the DELETE key.

(Probably need word-wrapping off.)

Comment: Wow, didn't know that Josh. Thanks! I do however want to create a series of Macros because I will be getting more and more of these CSV files in that I need to remove the first character of and some of them  have thousands of lines :)

Comment: I wish I can give more than one up vote. Thank you