# Notepad++: How to trim strings to a maximum length in a huge file?

Tags: notepad++, regex, string-manipulation

community i need your help, please!

i want to trim strings in a file with about 900000 lines:

KAA

BSJDKWLADDKHUEW

AJMJJ

GMEMJRGUMGA

GJWEGRJGJALUSGEUIGRL

AGUGADJF

WE

.....

I Want to trim all strings to a maximum length of 5 (trimming the END of each line):

KAA

BSJDK

AJMJJ

GMEMJ

GJWEG

AGUGA

WE

.....

Is there a quick way to do this with regular expressions? (In column mode (ALT+Shift) notepad++ crashes always, with macro i have no experience)

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Using Notepad++:

Find what: `^([^\n]{5}).*?$`

Replace with: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Use notepad++ `Search>Replace` option

In Find: `([0-9A-Za-z]{5})`

In Replace : `$1\n`

Comment: Thank you sreekanth! Unfortunately your code does something like:                                                                  notep                                                               ad  answe                                                               r                                                                                                                                       the code trims correctly the string, it moves the trimmed part in the next line! Any suggestions?

Comment: The trimmed part should be deleted!

Comment: Its my mistake I thought it should be forward to next line

Comment: I don't have an idea please refer to this http://superuser.com/questions/339601/how-would-i-delete-the-first-27-characters-from-every-line-notepad